# Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->findResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URL; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied) creating url

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the OMDB api to make a search app in Android Studio, i was debuging the code to find another error and i don't know why the logd url stopped giving me the right url and started saying:

Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->findResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URL; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$Element;->findResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URL; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)

To create this Url i have the global string from the api url format:

`private String link = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=XXXXX=";`

A global string that is the text entered into my editText passed from the MainActivity into the fragment via Constructor, by debugging i'm sure that this variable is working:

```
private String movieToSearch;

public ListFragment(String movie) {
        // Required empty public constructor
        movieToSearch = movie;
}
```

A function that adds the text entered in my EditText into the url:

```
private String generateUrl(){
        String url;
        url = link += movieToSearch;
        return url;
}
```

And then i'm calling that function in my DoInBackgroud in the AsyncTask to generate the url to connect:

```
URL strApiUrl;
String url = generateUrl();
Log.d("url", url);
```

And i don't think this affects anything because i want to Log the Url as a string before i pass it as a URL variable but just in case i declare the variable one line up from the String url and then  after i declare other variables like a context to make some toasts i open a Try and in there i wrote
`strApiUrl = new URL(url);` but i don't think that affects my error message. Thanks for your patience and time if you reached here.

Comment: Every time you call `generateUrl()` you change the variable `link`! Maybe that's a typo and you wanted to write `url = link + movieToSearch;`. Why do you need `generateUrl()` anyway? You could also write `String url = link + movieToSearch;` directly.

Comment: Android Fragment constructors are supposed to be empty. That isn't how you give field parameters to them, but can you show the rest of your code as a [mcve] rather than try to explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I tried making another `AsyncTask` to try to solve my first problem, and in my `OnCreateView` instead of making a function like this:

```
private void Task() {
    MyAsyncTask miTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    miTask.execute();
}
```

And then in my main activity calling the Task function I wrote just `MyAsynkTask();` on my `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score -1):

To solve that problem I turn off vpn connection.